# How do you print the items in a nested list line by line in Python?

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

For example, if I have:

```
l = [["apple", "orange", "banana"], ["grape", "strawberry", "raspberry"]]
```

I'd like if it could print:

```
["apple", "orange", "banana"]

["grape", "strawberry", "raspberry"]
```

instead of:

```
[["apple", "orange", "banana"], ["grape", "strawberry", "raspberry"]]
```

Easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty much tasked to break down that nested array as much as possible.

```
for i in arr:
    print(i)
```

But let's say you had a double nested array.
You could do:

```
for i in arr:
    for inArr in i:
        print(i)
```

If you had a triple nested and wanted to print each, you you do.

```
for i in arr:
    for inArr in i:
        for subArr in inArr:
            print(subArr)
```

We use a foreach for each index and then keep using a foreach to look through an even deeper index.

> I know you only asked for the first one, but I wanted to give a unique
>   and in depth answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `for` loop and iterate through each item in the list:

```
for item in l:
    print item
```